# Teradata - can't collapse overlapping rows and preserve gaps

Tags: teradata

Given this lovely data set with various gaps and overlapping records:

```
+---+--------+------+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
|   | BUS_LN | SGMT | STATE | TheID | ASSGND_TO |   EFF_DT   |   END_DT   |
+---+--------+------+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1 | A      | B    | LA    | 12345 | AAA       | 2015-01-01 | 2015-06-30 |
| 2 | A      | B    | LA    | 12345 | AAA       | 2015-10-01 | 2015-12-31 |
| 3 | A      | B    | LA    | 12345 | AAA       | 2016-01-01 | 2016-02-29 |
| 4 | A      | B    | LA    | 12345 | AAA       | 2016-03-01 | 2017-12-31 |
| 5 | A      | B    | LA    | 12345 | AAA       | 2018-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| 6 | A      | B    | LA    | 67890 | BBB       | 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-01 |
| 7 | A      | B    | LA    | 67890 | BBB       | 2016-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |
| 8 | A      | B    | LA    | 67890 | CCC       | 2017-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
| 9 | A      | B    | LA    | 67890 | BBB       | 2018-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
+---+--------+------+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

How can I collapse the overlaps while preserving the gaps and changes? 
There is a gap between rows 1 and 2.
Rows 3 thru 5 overlap.
Rows 6 and 7 overlap.

It should end up as:

```
+--------+------+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
| BUS_LN | SGMT | STATE | TheID | ASSGND_TO |   EFF_DT   |   END_DT   |
+--------+------+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
| A      | B    | LA    | 12345 | AAA       | 2015-01-01 | 2015-06-30 |
| A      | B    | LA    | 12345 | AAA       | 2015-10-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| A      | B    | LA    | 67890 | BBB       | 2015-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |
| A      | B    | LA    | 67890 | CCC       | 2017-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
| A      | B    | LA    | 67890 | BBB       | 2018-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
+--------+------+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I've been going in different circles all day, most recently with the incredibly poorly documented `TD_NORMALIZE_OVERLAP_MEET` function, but I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: There was a similar question a few days ago, you can probably use `select normalize`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661936/2527905

Comment: Not sure how I missed that!  I really need to break down and learn how to use the various period functionality one of these days.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the Temporal -functionality of Teradata:
- it provides a PERIOD Datatype (instead of two date fields)
- it provides functions to normalize / explode / overlap / summarize the valid date period.